# Isolating peaks in from time series data in R

Tags: r

I am working with 15-min streamflow data (one column of datetime, one of streamflow). I would like to write code that finds peaks (storms) over a certain threshold and select the data after until the data drops back down to a baseflow threshold. I would like to isolate these peak-and-recession sections, and then select those same time periods from other time-series data of water quality metrics.

I have tried the findpeaks function of the pracma package, and the output it gives me is the index of the peak and its start and endpoints, but I don't know how to convert these indices back to datetimes so I can select from the other time series.

I also have tried the find.spell.lengths from the Hystrostats package. It returns the spell length but I don't know how to convert that back to datetime intervals. Also this package seems to be designed for daily data (not 15-minute data) so I don't know if that will mess up the results.

Is there a different package or function I should be using, or a better way to do this?

Comment: Hi BeckyF, I think the pracma package seems to be ok. Maybe you can help by providing an example dataset you have with that, and also the code you have tried? Once you have the index, getting back the datetime is not a problem

Comment: So I used pracma like this
'peaks <-findpeaks(df$streamflow, minpeakheight = 1, minpeakdistance = 4,  sortstr = FALSE)'

I don't really know how to attach data to this comment, but the data.frame I wam working with has one column of datetimes in POSIX format, and one of streamflow (numeric )

Comment: No worries. So you do dput(df), and it returns you an output, it starts with structure( ...) , copy paste that onto your post. And also include your code as well.. Yeah I can take a quick look

Comment: the output from dput() is too long, but I can do this:
head(stream_data)
# A tibble: 6 x 2
  datetime            streamflow
  <dttm>                   <dbl>
1 2018-09-27 10:00:00      0.550
2 2018-09-27 10:15:00      0.544
3 2018-09-27 10:30:00      0.534
4 2018-09-27 10:45:00      0.557
5 2018-09-27 11:00:00      0.536
6 2018-09-27 11:15:00      0.535

To find peaks I used:
'peaks <-findpeaks(stream_data$streamflow, minpeakheight = 1, minpeakdistance = 4,  sortstr = FALSE)'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are almost there. I just simulated some data and use the pracma package. You mentioned having problems getting the dates back, what you do is use the index returned from the findpeak call, and subset your dataframe according to that,

For example, to get datetime of the absolute peak, do:

```
peaks <-findpeaks(stream_data$streamflow, minpeakheight = 1, minpeakdistance = 4, sortstr = FALSE)
stream_data[peaks[,2],"datetime"]
```

so see below code on how to call them back.

```
library(pracma)
#simulate data using pracma findpeaks example
x <- seq(0, 1, len = 1024)
     pos <- c(0.1, 0.13, 0.15, 0.23, 0.25, 0.40, 0.44, 0.65, 0.76, 0.78, 0.81)
     hgt <- c(4, 5, 3, 4, 5, 4.2, 2.1, 4.3, 3.1, 5.1, 4.2)
     wdt <- c(0.005, 0.005, 0.006, 0.01, 0.01, 0.03, 0.01, 0.01, 0.005, 0.008, 0.005)

pSignal <- numeric(length(x))
for (i in seq(along=pos)) {
             pSignal <- pSignal + hgt[i]/(1 + abs((x - pos[i])/wdt[i]))^4
     }

#give a datetime
START = as.POSIXlt("2018-09-07 10:00:00")
END = as.POSIXlt("2018-09-16 10:00:00")
#make your data frame
stream_data = data.frame(
       datetime=seq(START,END,length.out=length(pSignal)),
       streamflow=pSignal)
#plot
with(stream_data,plot(datetime,streamflow,type="l"))
#call peaks like you did
peak <-findpeaks(stream_data$streamflow, minpeakheight = 1, minpeakdistance = 4, sortstr = FALSE)
## call
data.frame(
       peak_number = 1:nrow(peak),
       peak_max = stream_data[peak[,2],"datetime"],
       peak_heigth = stream_data[peak[,2],"streamflow"],
       peak_start = stream_data[peak[,3],"datetime"],
       peak_end = stream_data[peak[,4],"datetime"]
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should provide some code to specify the types of data you're working with. If you are working with a dataframe or even a vector, you could use a Boolean index

```
# a dataframe of dates and flows
df <- # dates and data

# initialize your threshold
threshold <- #something

# get the indices of data that are greater than threshold
peak_indices <- df$stream_data >= threshold

# dates that are cover the peak intervals
peak_dates <- df$dates[peak_indices]
```

**Edit**

Didn't see your comment that it is a dataframe! My apologies.

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion. I load in each data set as a data.frame. but then convert it to xts so I can match up my various time series data sets for plotting.

Comment: The code you mentioned did work
threshold <- 1
peak_indices <- df$streamflow >= threshold
peak_dates <- df$datetime[peak_indices]

But the output for both peak_indices and peak_dates is a vector (not a table). How would I create a table with the dates in one column and values over that threshold in the other?

This is what I tried
peak_flows <- df$streamflow[peak_indices]
StormsOnly <- cbind(peak_dates, peak_flows)

This will put them together but then I lose the POSIXct format for the dates
StormsOnly <- as.data.frame(cbind(peak_dates, peak_flows))